# AWS Serverless template resource count exceeds

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services

I have just started migrating all my Web APIs to AWS serverless functions using VS2015 dot net core. I have total 60 resources(AWS::Serverless::Function) defined in serverless.template file. When I started uploading it through Visual Studio (Publish to AWS Lamda), I got below error.

> Failed to create CloudFormation change set: Template format error: Number of resources, 267, is greater than maximum allowed, 200

I tried deleting some resources but same error comes repeatedly. Initially when I do it by just having 2,3 resources, it was working just fine.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Edit:
Below is new master template referring nested stack

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
    "Transform" : "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
    "Resources" : {
        "FirstStack" : {
           "Type" : "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
           "Properties" : {
              "TemplateURL" : "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/serverless1.template",
              "TimeoutInMinutes" : "60"
           }          
        },
        "SecondStack" : {
           "Type" : "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
           "Properties" : {
              "TemplateURL" : "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/serverless2.template",
              "TimeoutInMinutes" : "60"
           }          
        }
    },    
    "Outputs": {

    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [Cloudformation Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cloudformation-limits.html) you'll see that 200 Resources is the max per template. Their recommendation is to use [Nested Stacks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Dave. I also read that but my question is that I am having only 60 resources in my serverless.template file. How resource count is calculated?

Comment: Each definition would be 1 lambda, 1 API gateway + possibly an IAM role and other associations which I believe is why you see a multiplier in aws Resource count. To test we could import 1 definition and then export the Cloudfront template to see every Resource provisioned.

Comment: Thanks. As you mentioned, I just separated my template into two pieces and kept it in S3. Created serverless.template with resource as stack. Now, it simply rollback without creating stack. Below is the sample template I am using. Can you help understand what is missing here?

Comment: I added sample template in my actual question (Edit)

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, any chance of solution for this issue

Answer (score 0):

AWS Changes Posted On:

- Oct 22, 2020

AWS Changes Posted At:

- https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/aws-cloudformation-now-supports-increased-limits-on-five-service-quotas/

### 5 Increased Cloudformation Limits

- #### maximum size of a template that can be passed in an S3 Object

  - **1MB**
  - *previously 450KB*
- #### per template limits for the **maximum number of resources**

  - **500**
  - *previously 200*
- #### parameters

  - **200**
  - *previously 60*
- #### mappings

  - **200**
  - *previously 100*
- #### outputs

  - **200**
  - *previously 60*